# How set Column format in GridView RowDataBound DataRow

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I have a GridView and in its RowDataBound event I am trying to set the format of a column to "dd MMM yyyy". I first check if RowType is DataRow,  My code is as shown below :

```
        If e.Row.RowType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim ColCount As Integer
        ColCount = e.Row.Cells.Count

        For looper = 0 To ColCount - 1

            Dim cell As TableCell = e.Row.Cells(looper)
            ' For now I have hardcoded the Table Name
            Dim TempTabName As String = "STAFF"
            Dim TempColName As String
            Dim TempColType As String

            Dim CurrCol As BoundField = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.Row.Cells(looper), DataControlFieldCell).ContainingField, BoundField)
            ' Extracting Column Name
            TempColName = CurrCol.HeaderText
            ' Extracting Column Type (varchar, datetime etc)
            TempColType = GetColType(TempTabName, TempColName)

            ' Depending on Column Type Set Format
            ' Depending on Column Type Set Format
            Select Case TempColType
                Case "varchar"
                    status.Text = "We are at varchar"
                Case "nvarchar"
                    status.Text = "We are at nvarchar"
                Case "char"
                    status.Text = "We are at char"
                Case "datetime"
                    status.Text = "We are at datetime"
                    CurrCol.DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}"                    
                Case "date"
                    status.Text = "We are at date"
                Case "time"
                    status.Text = "We are at time"
                Case "float"
                    status.Text = "We are at float"
            End Select
        Next
    End If
```

When I run this code on line CurrCol.DataFormatString I get the error "Exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code". Additional Info: Specified method is not supported

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Or can someone please explain with some sample code of how to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can direct set date format in Gridview HTML Markup.

If you using itemTemplate then your sample code looks like

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label 
           ID="Label1" 
           runat="server" 
           Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "date_of", "{0:dd MMM yyyy}") %>'>
        </asp:Label> 
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Here `date_of` if the column name, which you want to format